# Custom HTML Element Registered to Shadow DOM

Tags: html, dom, polymer

I have created a [platformjs custom element](http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/custom-elements.html) that extends form, lets call it x-form. I've wrapped x-form inside of a polymer element named super-form. I'm doing this because I want to keep the encapsulation of the javascript and css to this single element. What I'd like to know is, is there a way to register the x-form to the shadow dom of super-form or otherwise restrict the use of x-form outside of the super-form element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > is there a way to register the x-form to the shadow dom of super-form or otherwise restrict the use of x-form

No way that is supplied by the system.

Comment: You could have an on-attached callback that threw an error if the x-form wasn't inside a superform.